Why is my laptop lagging while using blender?
I'm trying to use Blender by following a youtube tutorial. The process is going pretty well, except my laptop is starting to lag and slowing down the process (while in the rendering part in the 3d viewport); making it hard for me to continue on. Is there a way that you or I can fix this please?
System Information
Operating system: Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0 64 Bits
Graphics card: Intel(R) UHD Graphics Intel 4.6.0 - Build 31.0.101.4032
Blender Version
Broken: version: version: 4.1.1, branch: blender-v4.1-release

Hello, it may be because your file is too heavy, what it is exactly, how many faces does your objects have?

I'm not really sure. All I'm trying to do is add materials, textures to the object, and use geometry nodes. I'm not able to tell of which file is too heavy, or how many faces my objects have. ‍♀️
